# ie 11 now takes 30 sec to start loading my start page

Tags: windows, windows-10

Internet Explorer 11 now takes 30 seconds to start, loading my start page (the BBC website). If I run IE with admin rights the same start page loads in 3 seconds.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you have any add-ons for it? How quickly does it load if you run `iexplore.exe -extoff`?

Comment: Normal IE 11 loads in protected mode, run as admin does not, not sure if this slows loading.

Comment: install the WPT, which is part of Win10 SDK: dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk, run WPRUI.exe, select CPU, disk, FileIO and under scenario "Internet Explorer", start the trace, start the IE, load the page, close IE, run IE again as admin, load the page again, close IE and stop the trace. Zip the saved ETL + ngenpdb folder into a ZIP, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a sharelink and post the link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Answer (score 0):

What you are stating sounds like add-on issues similar to what @Junno stated. As @Junno stated, try starting IE in safe mode, this will disable all add-ons. If you find that the website you are visiting is performing better relaunch IE in normal mode and disable/enable add-on until the website works for you.

How to start IE in safe mode.

1. Open a Command Prompt
2. Type (with quotes) "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -extoff

Comment: The user wants to fix IE11.  The question has nothing to do with Edge.

Comment: Removed edge info as per @Ramhound suggested.